# reload tableView after editing with animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i want to reload the tableView when the animation finish.

here is my code

```
  -(void)btnEditClicked{
    toolbar.hidden=!toolbar.hidden;
    editToolbar.hidden=!editToolbar.hidden;
    if (!tblView.editing) {
        [arrSelectedRows removeAllObjects];
        [tblView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [Utility setRightBarButtonItemWithTarget:self withAction:@selector(btnEditClicked) andWithImage:@"done_btn.png"];
    }
    else{
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [Utility setRightBarButtonItemWithTarget:self withAction:@selector(btnEditClicked) andWithImage:@"edit_btn.png"];
        [tblView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
    }
   // [tblView reloadData]; if i use this line then the animation not working.
}
```

so is there any methods that call after aniation finish?
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try:

```
[tblView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.3];
```